# Two chains on Eris

Tags: private-blockchain, ubuntu, eris-industries, docker

I have set up Eris on my ubuntu machine using Docker.I have created private blockchain. Eris tools provides option to work on multiple chains using  below tool.

```
>> eris chains <start|stop|new|ls>
```

I have created 2-3 chains(private) on eris platform.

```
CHAIN            ON     CONTAINER ID     DATA CONTAINER
simple_chain     -      ad1c0920ca       90a8408016
demochain        *      68da9f15ee       adf1d1a184
testchain        -      ec4f7873c2       abaac8d953
```

A star(*) marked against demochain specifies that this chain is active(or running) right now. If I want to deploy a contract on testchain , I have to stop demochain and start testchain.

My question is this why cant we have two(or more) chains running at same time in Eris.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple chains running at once on the Eris platform is indeed possible. To do this, for each chain, when you run `eris chains new|start`, add the `--publish` flag which will randomize the ports and allow multiple chains to be running at once. Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this my running different chains on different ports. This is possible by either using `--publish` or by using `--ports` flag. If you use `--publish` flag then it will randomise the ports. If you use `--ports` flag then you can specify the ports on which you want to run a particular chain. To read more on ports, use the [eris documentation](https://monax.io/docs/documentation/cli/0.11.4/eris_chains_new/).